Power Query SQL - Slicer values displays as text instead of Date data type
Hi I have created dynamic M query which passes input slicer (i.e start date and End date)
The Query i have writen as below
filterquery = "SELECT * FROM Schema1.TabName where ""date"" >= '" & DateTime.ToText(StartDate,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' And ""date"" <= '" & DateTime.ToText(Date.AddDays( Enddate,1),"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"

Here I have created start date and end date parameters as "Date/time" format and bind to parameters from slicer tables.

Now i am unable to convert them as calander date picker,any modification need to be done in above Query?

H,ello, Have you tried the date format instead of the date time ?

Yes , i have tried with changing datetime to date but not getting required output

You have a yyyy/MM/dd format in your query, but your data is M/d/yyyy. Have you tried modifying the format ?

The issue is the Date.ToText()
All in all, either get the date in a different format or add a Change type back with DateTime.FromText() for example

Thanks, i have tried with above and getting error as   Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #datetime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) to type Text.
Details:
Value=1/1/2024 12:00:00 AM
Type=[Type]

@san1 you're right, it should be Datetime.FromText() .Date and Datetime are different types :)
I edited it in my response
